# Loading a 3rd party embed widget within an Ember.View

Tags: ember.js

I'm loading the RebelMouse embed widget into an Ember.View, like so:

```
App.RebelMouseView = Em.View.extend({
didInsertElement: function() {
var widgetEmbedCode = '<script type="text/javascript" class="rebelmouse-embed-script" src="https://www.rebelmouse.com/static/js-build/embed/embed.js?site=W3portals&height=900&flexible=1"></script>';

  this.$().append(widgetEmbedCode);
  }
});
```

But I'm hoping there's a better way to do so.

One undesired side-effect is that everytime I initialize that view it reloads the entire widget with a 1 second delay. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, good idea on showing/hiding, see http://jsfiddle.net/9EC8F/ for how to do it. Basically, the trick is to keep the view outside any outlet that will be torn up when the route changes. Then, put this in your route:

```
activate: function() {
    $(".rebel-mouse-view").show();
},
deactivate: function () {
    $(".rebel-mouse-view").hide();
}
```

and this in your view:

```
classNames: ['rebel-mouse-view'],
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how this particular 3rd party widget works.

Comment: Maybe it would help to put the script tag in an iframe?

Comment: Still the same issue with the loading delay everytime the view is rendered. Is there a way to load the script on app load and then show/hide the view in the route?

Comment: Did you get a chance to try this out?